# Does argparse (python) support mutually exclusive groups of arguments?

Tags: python, argparse

If I have the arguments `'-a', '-b', '-c', '-d'`, with the `add_mutually_exclusive_group()` function my program will have to use just one of them. Is there a way to combine that, so that the program will accept only either `'-a 999 -b 999'` or `'-c 999 -d 999'`?

**Edit:** adding a simple program for more clarity:

```
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
>>> group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
>>> group.add_argument('-a')
>>> group.add_argument('-b')
>>> group.add_argument('-c')
>>> group.add_argument('-d')
```

Then only `./app.py -a | ./app.py -b | ./app.py -c | ./app.py -d` can be called. Is it possible to have argparse group the exclusion groups, so that only `./app.py -a .. -b .. | ./app.py -c .. -d ..` be called?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**EDIT**: Never mind. Because `argparse` makes the horrible choice of having to create an option when invoking `group.add_argument`. That wouldn't be my design choice. If you're desperate for this feature, you can try doing it with [ConflictsOptionParser](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/ConflictsOptionParser/):

```
# exclusivegroups.py
import conflictsparse

parser = conflictsparse.ConflictsOptionParser()
a_opt = parser.add_option('-a')
b_opt = parser.add_option('-b')
c_opt = parser.add_option('-c')
d_opt = parser.add_option('-d')

import itertools
compatible_opts1 = (a_opt, b_opt)
compatible_opts2 = (c_opt, d_opt)
exclusives = itertools.product(compatible_opts1, compatible_opts2)
for exclusive_grp in exclusives:
    parser.register_conflict(exclusive_grp)


opts, args = parser.parse_args()
print "opts: ", opts
print "args: ", args
```

Thus when we invoke it, we can see we get the desired effect.

```
$ python exclusivegroups.py -a 1 -b 2
opts:  {'a': '1', 'c': None, 'b': '2', 'd': None}
args:  []
$ python exclusivegroups.py -c 3 -d 2
opts:  {'a': None, 'c': '3', 'b': None, 'd': '2'}
args:  []
$ python exclusivegroups.py -a 1 -b 2 -c 3
Usage: exclusivegroups.py [options]

exclusivegroups.py: error: -b, -c are incompatible options.
```

The warning message doesn't inform you that both `'-a'` and `'-b'` are incompatible with `'-c'`, however a more appropriate error message could be crafted. Older, wrong answer below.

**OLDER EDIT:** *[This edit is wrong, although wouldn't it be just a perfect world if `argparse` worked this way?]* My previous answer actually was incorrect, you should be able to do this with `argparse` by specifying one group per mutually exclusive options. We can even use `itertools` to generalize the process. And make it so we don't have to type out all the combinations explicitly:

```
import itertools
compatible_opts1 = ('-a', '-b')
compatible_opts2 = ('-c', '-d')
exclusives = itertools.product(compatible_opts1, compatible_opts2)
for exclusive_grp in exclusives:
    group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
    group.add_argument(exclusive_grp[0])
    group.add_argument(exclusive_grp[1])
```

Comment: http://bugs.python.org/issue10984 has a patch that lets you put an argument into more than one mutually exclusive group.  Doing that is an easy change.  Producing a meaningful usage with overlapping groups is more involved.

Answer (score 5):

Just stumbled on this problem myself. From my reading of the argparse docs, there doesn't seem to be a simple way to achieve that within argparse. I considered using parse_known_args, but that soon amounts to writing a special-purpose version of argparse ;-)

Perhaps a bug report is in order. In the meanwhile, if you're willing to make your user do a tiny bit extra typing, you can fake it with subgroups (like how git and svn's arguments work), e.g.

```
    subparsers = parser.add_subparsers()
    p_ab = subparsers.add_parser('ab')
    p_ab.add_argument(...)

    p_cd = subparsers.add_parser('cd')
    p_cd.add_argument(...)
```

Not ideal, but at least it gives you the good from argparse without too much ugly hackery. I ended up doing away with the switches and just using the subparser operations with required subarguments.

Answer (score 4):

The `argparse` enhancement request referenced in @hpaulj's comment is still open after more than nine years, so I figured other people might benefit from the workaround I just discovered. Based on [this comment](https://bugs.python.org/issue10984#msg219660) in the enhancement request, I found I was able to add an option to two different mutually-exclusive groups using this syntax:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python                                                                                                                                                                     
import argparse
import os
import sys

def parse_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        formatter_class=argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter
    )

    parser.add_argument("-d", "--device", help="Path to UART device", default="./ttyS0")

    mutex_group1 = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
    mutex_group2 = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()

    mutex_group1.add_argument(
        "-o",
        "--output-file",
        help="Name of output CSV file",
        default="sensor_data_sent.csv",
    )

    input_file_action = mutex_group1.add_argument(
        "-i", "--input-file", type=argparse.FileType("r"), help="Name of input CSV file"
    )

    # See: https://bugs.python.org/issue10984#msg219660
    mutex_group2._group_actions.append(input_file_action)

    mutex_group2.add_argument(
        "-t",
        "--time",
        type=int,
        help="How long to run, in seconds (-1 = loop forever)",
        default=-1,
    )

    # Add missing ']' to usage message
    usage = parser.format_usage()
    usage = usage.replace('usage: ', '')
    usage = usage.replace(']\n', ']]\n')
    parser.usage = usage

    return parser.parse_args()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    args = parse_args()
    print("Args parsed successfully...")
    sys.exit(0)
```

This works well enough for my purposes:

```
$ ./fake_sensor.py -i input.csv -o output.csv                                                                                                                                             
usage: fake_sensor.py [-h] [-d DEVICE] [-o OUTPUT_FILE | [-i INPUT_FILE | -t TIME]]
fake_sensor.py: error: argument -o/--output-file: not allowed with argument -i/--input-file

$ ./fake_sensor.py -i input.csv -t 30         
usage: fake_sensor.py [-h] [-d DEVICE] [-o OUTPUT_FILE | [-i INPUT_FILE | -t TIME]]
fake_sensor.py: error: argument -t/--time: not allowed with argument -i/--input-file

$ ./fake_sensor.py -i input.csv
Args parsed successfully...

$ ./fake_sensor.py -o output.csv
Args parsed successfully...

$ ./fake_sensor.py -o output.csv -t 30
Args parsed successfully...
```

Accessing private members of `argparse` is, of course, rather brittle, so I probably wouldn't use this approach in production code. Also, an astute reader may notice that the usage message is misleading, since it implies that `-o` and `-i` can be used together when they cannot(!) However, I'm using this script for testing only, so I'm not overly concerned. (Fixing the usage message 'for real' would, I think, require *much* more time than I can spare for this task, but please comment if you know a clever hack for this.)

Answer (score 0):

**Subparsers?**

Similar to *unhammer*'s answer, but with more user control.  Note:  I have not actually tested this method, but it should work in theory and with the capabilities of python.

You can create two parsers, one for each of the two groups, and use conditionals to do the mutually exclusive part.  Essentially using argparse for only part of the argument parsing.  Using this method, you can go beyond the limitations of *unhammer*'s answer as well.

```
# Python 3
import argparse

try:
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-a')
    parser.add_argument('-b')
    args = parser.parse_args
except argparse.ArgumentError:
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-c')
    parser.add_argument('-d')
    args = parser.parse_args
```