# Argparse groups in

Tags: python, argparse

Using python's argparse module I want to pass parameters to prog two ways:

Method 1:

```
./filter.py filename --start_regex "^FOO" --end_regex "BAR$" --contains "XXX" --bunch_of_common_options
```

Method 2:

`./filter.py filename --type "FOO_BAR_XXX" --bunch_of_common_options`

Logically both are doing exactly the same, because there is a dict in `filter.py` that translates "FOO_BAR_XXX" type from method 2 to appropriate options for method 1.

I want to specify that, given:

> groupA = (--start_regex, --end_regex --contains)
>
> groupB = (--type)

groupA and groupB are:

1. mutually exclusive, and
2. groupA must have at least start_regex
   defined

Now, I'm aware of [mutually_exclusive_group](http://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#mutual-exclusion) functionality, but it works only on single arguments (not groups of options), and [sub-commands](http://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#sub-commands), but it looks like I would have to have some kind of dispatch option after prog.py, like "git clone --help", or "git push --help" ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17909294/python-argparse-mutual-exclusive-group) post proves that)

Note that it's not elegant to say:

```
./filter.py with_type filename --type TYPE1
./filter.py without_type filename --start_regex "^FOO" --end_regex "BAR$" --contains "XXX"
```

Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

`groups` don't affect the parsing in any significant way.  The regular `argument groups` just affect the `help` formatting (you might want to define such groups just for that purpose).  Mutually exclusive groups affect the usage formatting (but you can make your own custom usage line), and issue an error message if they are violated.  But you could just as well do that kind of test after `parse_args`, and even use `argparse.error` to produce a formatted error message.  You could also do 'mutually inclusive' tests after.

There is a 'python issue' that explores putting an argument into more than one mutually exclusive group.  In this case you could make 3 groups, one for each of the Group A arguments, and put the `--type` argument in each.  That addition was easy; formatting a meaningful `usage` took more work.  See the linked SO issue.

I think doing your own tests after is best choice.

---

A couple of other options:

Write a custom Action, or Actions.  The 'regex_end' action, could for example, object if the namespace does not already have a 'regex_begin' value, or has a 'type' value. The 'type' action could check its format, and object if one of the others has been set already.  But you'd be doing the same tests in the post-parse_args case.

A `'--regex', nargs=3, metavar=('begin','end','content')` argument. That could be mutually exclusive with `--type`.  You could even designate the group as required.