# argparse module: require arg1 or (arg2 and arg3)

Tags: python, argparse

I'm aware of requiring one argument or another by putting arguments under a group and adding required as true. For example:

```
group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
group.add_argument('-1', '--arg1')
group.add_argument('-2', '--arg2')
```

this gives a usage of script.py (-1 || -2)
and is described as 'mutually exclusive' arguments: https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#mutual-exclusion

What I'm looking for is how to have:
usage script.py (-1 || -2 && -3)
and what is this described as/termed?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17909294/python-argparse-mutual-exclusive-group

Comment: The situation in 2013 still applies - you need to write your own test after parsing.  And if needed your own `usage` message.  Edit your question if you need something more specific.

Comment: thanks, I'd hoped for a more elegant recent answer but looks like nothing newer has been implemented in the argparse module