# Python argparse mutually exclusive with optional arguments

Tags: python, argparse

My requirement is to achieve following with argparse:

```
script.py <command> (-a|--first-name [--middle-name] [--last-name])
```

So basically, the script would accept one mandatory parameter , which can have different values. And then another parameter which should either be -a or --first-name.
Then first-name can have further parameters.

I was exploring subparsers and mutually exclusive group, but can't figure out how to achieve this

One crude way I am handling this is

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='myscript', usage='%(prog)s <command> (-a|--first-name [--middle-name] [--last-name])')
parser.add_argument('command')

mxgroup = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
mxgroup.add_argument('-a', action='store_true', help='Choose all')
mxgroup.add_argument('--first-name', dest='fname')

parser.add_argument('--middle-name', dest='mname')
parser.add_argument('--last-name', dest='lname')

args = parser.parse_args()

if (args.mname or args.lname) and not args.fname:
    parser.error('middle and last names may be specified with first name only')
```

But I am thinking if these checks can be handled by argparse inherently then I won't have to redo it as the script grows

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: So you want to let the user specify `--middle-name` and `--last-name` *only* if they also specify `--first-name`? Is there any dependency between `--middle-name` and `--last-name`? Or can the user specify just first name + last name or first name + middle name?

Comment: No dependency between middle and last name. But user must specify either -a or --first-name along with mandatory <command>

Comment: Is `<command>` a fixed string? If so you can use the `add_subparsers` and simply specif `--first-name` as a `required=True` argument for the subparser.

Comment: <command> is not fixed. It can take different values

Comment: Then that's a problem. I don't think there is any way to do this using built-in methods, you'll have to specify the arguments you need and then manually check whether the user provided the right set and if not manually print an error and show the help message.

Comment: The only alternativet that I could see would be to change your syntax using subparsers, i.e. change `-a` and `--first-name` to be subparsers. and so you'd have: `script.py a <command>` and `script.py first-name <command> [--middle-name] [--last-name]`.   Note that `argparse` has some limitations that are enforced to avoid weird command lines, and one rule of thumb is that options should be *optional*.

Comment: Yeah I thought of that too, but then -a and --first-name in my case don't qualify as separate commands so they don't deserve subparsers. I even tried add_parser('-a') for the subparsers, but calling it from command line they are still treated as -a option and not subparser command

Comment: Subparser names should **not** start with hyphens. That's why I said that you have to **change** the syntax, from `-a` and `--first-name` to `a` and `first-name`.   Also: whether or not this makes sense depends on what you are dealing with, and currently you didn't provide enough information to know whether it's okay or not.

Comment: That duplicate suggests what he's already doing - a post-parsing test, or an `nargs` alternative (which I repeat below).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing crude about testing values after parsing.  All the `mutually exclusive group` does is format the `usage` (which you've probably already seen), and test each argument in the group against a set of 'already-seen' actions.   There's no nesting or compound logic testing, just a simple, flat, `xor`.

I'd suggest a `('--name', nargs='+', help='name - first [last [middle]]')` kind of argument.  That is, accept one or more strings for the `name`.  The result will be a list, which you can easily parse as the 3 parts.  It even lets you user specify a 4 part name, or one of those aristocratic 10 part ones.

Some of the sidebar questions explore this in more detail, for example

[Python argparse mutual exclusive group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17909294/python-argparse-mutual-exclusive-group)