# Variable length arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

I am creating a python program using the [`argparse` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) and I want to allow the program to take either one argument or 2 arguments.

What do I mean?  Well, I am creating a program to download/decode MMS messages and I want the user to either be able to provide a phone number and MMS-Transaction-ID to download the data or provide a file from their system of already downloaded MMS data.

What I want is something like this, where you can either enter in 2 arguments, or 1 argument:

```
./mms.py (phone mmsid | file)
```

<sub>NOTE: `phone` would be a phone number (like `15555555555`), `mmsid` a string (MMS-Transaction-ID) and `file` a file on the user's computer</sub>

Is this possible with `argparse`?  I was hoping I could use `add_mutually_exclusive_group`, but that didn't seem to do what I want.

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
group.add_argument('phone', help='Phone number')
group.add_argument('mmsid', help='MMS-Transaction-ID to download')
group.add_argument('file', help='MMS binary file to read')
```

This gives the error (removing `required=True` gives the same error):

> ValueError: mutually exclusive arguments must be optional

It looks like it wants me to use `--phone` instead of `phone`:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
group.add_argument('--phone', help='Phone number')
group.add_argument('--mmsid', help='MMS-Transaction-ID to download')
group.add_argument('--file', help='MMS binary file to read')
```

When running my program with no arguments, I see:

> error: one of the arguments --phone --mmsid --file is required

This is closer to what I want, but can I make `argparse` do `(--phone --msid) or (--file)`?

Comment: Could you use [subcommands](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#sub-commands)?

Comment: @mgilson: I didn't look into that.  Is there a way to make a "default" command?  Like `./mms.py file.bin` instead of `./mms.py decode file.bin` or `./mms.py 15555555555 abcd` instead of `./mms.py download 15555555555 abcd`.

Comment: That's a good question.  I don't see anything documented :-/...

Comment: @mgilson: Using subcommands *does* seem like a decent idea here, that way each one can have its own list of arguments it needs.

Comment: You mean something like http://stackoverflow.com/q/17909294/3001761?

Comment: @jonrsharpe: Yeah, that's basically the same thing I am trying to do.  Subcommands seems like a great idea for this.

Comment: The suggested duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17909294/python-argparse-mutual-exclusive-group, is about nesting groups of optionals.  This question is about handling 3 positionals.  That question may help, but it is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a little beyond the scope of what `argparse` can do, as the "type" of the first argument isn't known ahead of time. I would do something like

```
import argparse

p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
p.add_argument("file_or_phone", help="MMS File or phone number")
p.add_argument ("mmsid", nargs="?", help="MMS-Transaction-ID")

args = p.parse_args()
```

To determine whether `args.file_or_phone` is intended as a file name or a phone number, you need to check whether or not `args.mmsid` is `None`.

Comment: This seems, more or less, like exactly what I was trying to do.  In my `file` argument, I had `type=argparse.FileType('rb')`.  I guess I'll have to manually call `open(args.file_or_phone, 'rb')` if needed.

Comment: Also, it looks like I can override the text displayed to show `./mms.py (phone mmsid | file)` (and maybe add an "only with phone number" to mmsid) and then process the arguments as needed.

Comment: You could define a custom action that, based on the value given, decide if it is a phone number or a file name and act accordingly. However, the argument itself would still be something like `p.add_argument("file_or_phone", action=MyCustomAction, help="...")`.

Comment: A variant would be to accept one argument with `nargs='+'`, and then parse the list based on length and content.  Though this is basically the same as looking at `sys.argv[1:]` directly.