# Can argparse argument requirement be conditional on other arguments?

Tags: python, argparse

I would like to make one argument be required or not depending on the value of another argument supplied. Here is what I tried

```
import argparse

argparser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

#instead of hard coding it to always be required like this
#argparser.add_argument('-n', '--name', help='Name', required=True)
#I tried to use a boolean condition in the argparse configuration
argparser.add_argument('-n', '--name', help='Name', required=(not empty))
argparser.add_argument('-e', '--empty', help='Empty execution', action="store_true")

args = argparser.parse_args();

empty = args.empty
name = args.name
```

this does not work. Of course, I can write my own input validation check as a workaround but I would prefer to do it using the conventional notation, if possible.

Can argparse argument requirement be conditional on other arguments through the canonical API?

Comment: In this case you want mutually exclusive flags, yes?

Comment: If so, there's a [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17909294/python-argparse-mutual-exclusive-group) already.

Comment: No.  We've discussed work arounds, but there's nothing built in.  While there is a `mutually-exclusive` tool, there isn't a mutually-inclusive one.

Comment: No. The way to do this is code after the `.parse_args()` call to validate whatever invariants you want to apply.

Comment: it would be a nice addition to the argparse API to be able to do this though.  just another wish list item...

Comment: I've worked on a patch for a bug/issue that seeks nested inclusive arguments.  Doing the test is trivial, but making a nice API is more work.  Especially producing a meaningful `usage`.  No one seems to think about how they would instruct their users.