# Python argparse mutually exclusive set of arguments but also has shared arguments

Tags: python, argparse

I would like to achieve the following behavior in argparse

```
pro [-a xxx | [-b yyy -c zzz]] -d uuu -e vvv -f www
```

This is an extension to the problem in ["Python argparse mutual exclusive group"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17909294/python-argparse-mutual-exclusive-group) which recommends using subparsers.

But in this case, creating two subparsers to make the set of arguments `-a` and set `-b` and `-c` exclusive means duplicating `-d`, `-e`, `-f` in each subparser.

Is there another way to do this within `argparse`? Or the checks will have to be done manually?

Comment: Btw a hack would be to use positional arguments with nargs and create a mutually-exclusive group, but in this case it's 2 sets of mutually-exclusive keyword arguments

Comment: Is it `-b or -c` or `-b and -c`?  If the second, why not define a `--bc` with `nargs=2`?  In any case, as discussed in the link, the existing testing in `argparse` is a simple flat `xor`, without any `and/or` subgroups.  But you can always do the required testing after parsing.  Just use `if args.a is None:` to test whether `-a` has been used or not.