# Check what group was used in python argparse

Tags: python, argparse

I need to have two mutually exclusive groups of arguments in python using ArgumentParser. 
I use approach suggested by [Jonathan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1116874/jonathan) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17909294/python-argparse-mutual-exclusive-group):

```
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(help = "You should explicitly specify either group_1 or gropup_2")
    parser_g1 = subparsers.add_parser("group_1")
    parser_g1.add_argument("group_1_arg1")

    parser_g2 = subparsers.add_parser("group_2")
    parser_g2.add_argument("group_2_arg1")
    parser_g2.add_argument("group_2_arg2")
```

It looks as correct approach, but the problem is to determinate which group was choosen in runtime.
If first argument was `group_1` I get exception assigning `args.group_2_arg1` and `args.group_2_arg2`.
If first argument was `group_2` I get exception assigning `args.group_1_arg1`

The exception is of kind `'Namespace' object has no attribute 'group_1_arg1'`
Is there any way to check which paser group was used, other, then inspecting Namespace? s

Comment: If you give `add_subparsers` a `dest` parameter, then that will be set to either `group_1` or `group_2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you noted, you can use `hasattar`. But, if there are a lot of arguments and combinations of arguments, you can use the `set_defaults` functionality of the sub-parsers (note the starred code):

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(help = "You should explicitly specify either group_1 or gropup_2")
parser_g1 = subparsers.add_parser("group_1")
parser_g1.add_argument("group_1_arg1")
parser_g1.set_defaults(group=1)          # ***

parser_g2 = subparsers.add_parser("group_2")
parser_g2.add_argument("group_2_arg1")
parser_g2.set_defaults(group=2)          # *** 

args = parser.parse_args()
print(args)
```

When running this script:

```
./my_script.py group_1 group_1_arg1
```

The result is:

```
Namespace(group=1, group_1_arg1='group_1_arg1')
          =======
```

As you can see, each group will have its own indicator that the group was used.

Answer (score 1):

Well, trivial answer is to use

```
if hasattr(args, 'group_1_arg1'):
```

and so for other arguments.