# python argparse - How to prevent by using a combination of arguments

Tags: python, argparse

In argparse, I want to prevent a particular combination of arguments. Lets see the sample code.

### Sample:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
parser.add_argument('--firstname', dest='fn', action='store')
parser.add_argument('--lastname', dest='ln', action='store')
parser.add_argument('--fullname', dest='full', action='store')
args = parser.parse_args()
```

For eg: `--firstname --lastname --fullname`

The user can run the code in 2 days.

### Way 1:

```
code.py --firstname myfirst --lastname mylast
```

### Way 2:

```
code.py --fullname myfullname
```

### Prevent

We should not use the combination `fistname, fullname` or `lastname, fullname`. If we use both, then it should not execute.

Can someone help me to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17909525/4793196) proposes (on a similar question) you can do something like the following by using subparsers for both cases:

```
# create the top-level parser
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=false)
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(help='help for subcommands')

# create the parser for the "full_name" command
full_name = subparsers.add_parser('full_name', help='full_name help')
full_name.add_argument('--fullname', dest='full', action='store')

# create the parser for the "separate_names" command
separate_names = subparsers.add_parser('separate_names', help='separate_names help')
separate_names.add_argument('--firstname', dest='fn', action='store')
separate_names.add_argument('--lastname', dest='ln', action='store')

args = parser.parse_args()
```

You can improve it even further by requiring both the first and last name of the user as it generally makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure that is an argparse specific behavior that is possible.   But as long as those items are going to their own variables in the argparse resposes its a simple set of programming to check which ones are set and issue a message and exit.

example (assuming the result of parsing is in argsvalue):

```
if argsvalue.fullname and (argsvalue.firstname or argsvalue.lastname):
   print ("missuse of name options.....")
```

This assumes the argparse default for the vars is None (then if anything is set in them they will test to true with the logic above...

Answer (score 1):

You can split your arguments into separate commands and use subparsers, for example:

```
import argparse


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers()

parser_clean = subparsers.add_parser('clean', description='clean build folder')
parser_clean.add_argument('--all', help='clean build folder and logs', action='store_true')

parser_deploy = subparsers.add_parser('deploy')
parser_deploy.add_argument('object')
parser_deploy.add_argument('--nc', help='no cleanup', action='store_true')

args = parser.parse_args()
```

Comment: This answer could be improved by tailoring it to the actual question.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution I've found useful if:

- You want to prevent a combination of arguments within your subparser.
- You want more control over the prevention by checking the arguments' values or other stuff according to your needs.

In the below example, I prevented a combination of '--horizontal left' and '--vertical up' in the 'move' subparser:

```
import argparse


# Custom action to prevent a combination of '--horizontal left' and '--vertical up'
class PreventUpLeftStoreAction(argparse.Action):
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        setattr(namespace, self.dest, values)
        if namespace.horizontal == 'left' and namespace.vertical == 'up':
            parser.error("invalid combination of arguments: '--horizontal left' and '--vertical up' are not allowed together")


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Main Parser')
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers()

parser_move = subparsers.add_parser('move')
parser_move.add_argument('--horizontal', action=PreventUpLeftStoreAction, choices=['left', 'right'], required=True)
parser_move.add_argument('--vertical', action=PreventUpLeftStoreAction, choices=['up', 'down'], required=True)

args = parser.parse_args()
print(args)
```