# python argparse mutally exclusive group

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line-arguments, argparse

I want to do this using python `argparse` module

```
myprog [-f val_f | [-a val_a -b val_b]]
```

Both arguments `-a` and `-b` can be used at the same time. Or can be used one argument. But argument `-f` can't be used with any of argument `-a` or `-b`.

Valid

```
myprog -f val_f
myprog -a val_a
myprog -b val_b
myprog -a val_a -b val_b
```

Invalid

```
myprog -f val_f -a val_a
myprog -f val_f -b val_b
myprog -f val_f -a val_a -b val_b
```

I found a same question from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17909294/python-argparse-mutual-exclusive-group). But it doesn't give an answer to my question.

How to do this? Any idea?

Comment: what's wrong with the link?  There's nothing new  in argparse for this.