# Argparse: Argument can only be used alone, no other arguments

Tags: python, arguments, argparse

Is there a way to make an argument strictly used alone, without other flags, or it throws an error?

```py
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='description')
parser.add_argument("-n", "--line-number", help="print line numbers", action="store_true")
parser.add_argument("-e", "--errors", action="store_true", help="errors")
parser.add_argument("--debug", action="store_true", help="debug")
```

So for example in the code above, I want `--debug` to be used alone. If there are any other flags it would throw an error, but the `-n` and `-e` flag can still be used together like in the example below.

```
$ python3 file.py --debug // It works
$ python3 file.py --debug -n -e // Error: --debug can only be used alone...
$ python3 file.py -n -e // Work together
$ python3 file.py -n // or alone
```

I've tried using groups and reading the documentation but I haven't found anything useful.

How can I implement this behavior?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python argparse mutual exclusive group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17909294/python-argparse-mutual-exclusive-group) "I've tried using groups and reading the documentation but I haven't found anything useful." Please try searching in that documentation for the part about "mutually exclusive groups". Also, did you know there is a [specific argparse tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/argparse.html) built right into the documentation?

Comment: One option is to just ignore the others.  Or test things after parsing and complain.  `help` and `version` have `Action` subclasses that "exit".  Otherwise, there isn't anything special in `argparse` for this.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel, a problem with `mutually_exclusive` is that doesn't have any provision for allowing the either-or-or-both of the other arguments.  It is a simple flat `xor`.

Comment: @hpaulj which, from what I can understand from the specification, is *perfectly fine*. One group contains the `debug` option, which must not be used in combination with anything else, per OP's description. the other group contains the `n` and `e` options, which can be used separately or with each other, but not with `debug`.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Based on my quick scan of the docs, `add_mutually_exclusive_group` means that the arguments within the group are mutually exclusive with each other, **not** that the 2 groups are mutually exclusive with each other. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Right, there are no subgroups in a mutually exclusive group.

Comment: my answer in the duplicate still stands

Comment: Sorry, my mistake.