# How to set a group optional which contains several required arguments?

Tags: python, argparse

I'm using the `argparse` module.

My script need four arguments: `arg1`, `arg2`, `group_arg1`, `group_arg2`. `arg1` and `arg2` are required. `group_arg1` and `group_arg2` are grouped and the group is optional.

My code:

```py
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Test.')
parser.add_argument('--arg1', type=str, required=True)
parser.add_argument('--arg2', type=str, required=True)
test_group = parser.add_argument_group(title='Grouped Arguments')  # Need to be optional
test_group.add_argument('--group_arg1', type=str, required=True)
test_group.add_argument('--group_arg2', type=str, required=True)
```

How to set a group optional which contains several required arguments?

For example:

Users must pass in `--arg1 xx --arg2 xx` or `--arg1 xx --arg2 xx --group_arg1 xx --group_arg2 xx`

Case `--arg1 xx --arg2 xx --group_arg1 xx` is not allowed.

Comment: An argument_group is just used for the `help`.  It does nothing to the parsing logic.  Also make sure that your requirements are easily explained.  `argparse` docs has plenty of examples of usage lines.

Comment: @hpaulj I see. Is there any other ways to implement my case?

Comment: If your use case is just two strings why not just do `--group_args value1 value2`? Set `nargs=2` and the flag itself would be optional

Comment: The links and comments this other recent SO may be relevant, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72399131/argparse-argument-can-only-be-used-alone-no-other-arguments

Answer (score 0):

You could define a custom function to evaluate if the arguments are required instead of just setting the boolean yourself

```
import argparse
import sys

def need_optionals():
    return bool(len(set(sys.argv).intersection(('--group_arg1', '--group_arg2'))))

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Test.')
parser.add_argument('--arg1', type=str, required=True)
parser.add_argument('--arg2', type=str, required=True)
# Need to be optional
test_group = parser.add_argument_group(title='Grouped Arguments')
test_group.add_argument('--group_arg1', type=str, required=need_optionals())
test_group.add_argument('--group_arg2', type=str, required=need_optionals())
print(parser.parse_args())
```

Comment: Actually I want to add six argument to the group. So the validation function will have a deep nested `if-else` block.  I'm wondering if the example in my use case is a common example.

Comment: And maybe I need more than one groups and they are not mutually exclusive

Comment: @AnnLin Maybe in that case the easier way would be to go with MYousefi's suggestion of giving 2 arguments with the same key.