# Is there a way to require a mutually exclusive group, where one of the groups has multiple options?

Tags: python, argparse

I would like a behavior where exactly one of

- `--a`
- `--b` AND `--c`

are required. I know how to do it if the second requirement were just `--b`:

```
group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
group.add_argument('--a', type=str)
group.add_argument('--b', type=str)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python argparse mutual exclusive group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17909294/python-argparse-mutual-exclusive-group)

Comment: Are you trying to make is so if `--b` is passed, then `--c` is required as well?  Or that the user can pass `--a` or either of `--b` or `--c`?

Comment: no nesting of groups like this.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would do it:

```py
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

# group 1 
parser.add_argument("--a", type=str)

# group 2 
parser.add_argument("--b", type=str)
parser.add_argument("--c", type=str)

args = parser.parse_args()

if args.a and (args.b or args.c):
    print("-a and -b|-c are mutually exclusive ...")
    sys.exit(2)
```