# Using mutually exclusive groups in argparse: How to channel logic based on groups?

Tags: python, command-line-interface, argparse

I want to have mutually exclusive arguments for my script and channel logic based on what has been specified by a user. What I currently have is this:

```py
supported_formats = ['xyz','mol','pdb']

defaults = {'extension':'xyz',
            'dirname':None,
            'name':None}

info = '''Add info here.'''

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description=info)
group1 = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
group2 = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()

group1.add_argument('-i', '--infile', help='Specify a file path to a names_smiles csv.')

group2.add_argument('-s', '--smiles', nargs='+', help='Specify your smiles (multiple possible).')
group2.add_argument('-n', '--name', nargs='+', help='Specify (a) name(s) for your molecule.')

parser.add_argument('-d', '--dirname', default=defaults['dirname'], help='Specify the name of the directory to which the coords files will be written.')
parser.add_argument('-x', '--extension', default=defaults['extension'], help='Specify the file extension for your output coordinates. No dot necessary. Supported formats: %s'%', '.join(supported_formats))

mutually_exclusive = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
mutually_exclusive.add_argument_group(group1)
mutually_exclusive.add_argument_group(group2)

args = parser.parse_args()
```

As you can see, `group1` and `group2` args are exclusive, while the last ones are not. I want to later channel execution based on these groups kind of like:

```py
if args.group1: # do Stuff for csv
    print('Using input file %s as input.'%os.path.basename(args.infile))

elif args.group2:
    print('Using manual input.')

else:
    sys.exit('No input specified.')
```

The problem is that argparse doesn't work like that. In order to achieve my desired functionality, I need to check for each args of each group indivudually like this:

```py
if args.infile:
    print("Group 1 logic")
elif args.name or args.smiles:
    print("Group 2 logic")
else:
    print("No valid arguments were provided.")
```

Right now that is not that big a deal. But I am planning on adding a lot of args in the future and I don't want to have an `if` statement with like 10 `or` components.

I have tried to find out if there is an iterator for args groups so that I could do something like:

```py
if any([subarg == True for subarg in args.group2.subargs]):
    print('Run group2 logic')
```

But a look at the docs and `dir(parser)` didn't give me anything like that.

Is this possible or do I have to manually add each argument for each group?

EDIT: The previous post does not answer my question since it was a general post about how to use mutually exclusive groups. I want to know how to check if any argument of a particular group has been specified and channel logic based on that info.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python argparse mutual exclusive group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17909294/python-argparse-mutual-exclusive-group)

Comment: A mutually_exclusive_group is a simple 'xor' test - between arguments (not groups of arguments).  That last group flattens everything.  Also when defining groups, it's best to define all arguments together, else the `usage` display will be messed up.  If simple groups don't work for you, do your own testing after parsing.  Your goal in parsing is to figure out what the user wants; you don't have to control and scold them for every "bad" combination of arguments.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, that link is 10 years old, at least the question and early answers.  MXGroups have not been 'enhanced' since then, in fact the limits on nesting groups have been tightened.  A major problem with implementing fancy logic with groups is the `usage`.  It's hard to display anything but simple 'xor' logic in simple usage line.

Comment: args.group1` does not exist.  The group is used for checking coo-occurrence , otherwise it is not used to group Actions in `args`, nor is it used in help formatting (except the usage)

Comment: people have used custom `Action` classes, and a custom `Namespace` class to implement some sort of groups within `args`.  But that  requires understanding a lot about the `argparse.py` code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your parser, without the last lines attempting to nest the groups in another group:

```
In [24]: supported_formats = ['xyz','mol','pdb']
    ...: 
    ...: defaults = {'extension':'xyz',
    ...:             'dirname':None,
    ...:             'name':None}
    ...: 
    ...: info = '''Add info here.'''
    ...: 
    ...: parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description=info)
    ...: group1 = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
    ...: group1.add_argument('-i', '--infile', help='Specify a file path to a names_smiles csv.')
    ...: group2 = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
    ...: group2.add_argument('-s', '--smiles', nargs='+', help='Specify your smiles (multiple possible).')
    ...: group2.add_argument('-n', '--name', nargs='+', help='Specify (a) name(s) for your molecule.')
    ...: 
    ...: parser.add_argument('-d', '--dirname', default=defaults['dirname'], help='Specify the name of the directory to which the coords files will be written.')
    ...: parser.add_argument('-x', '--extension', default=defaults['extension'], help='Specify the file extension for your output coordinates. No dot necessary. Supported formats: %s'%', '.join(supported_formats))
```

And the resulting `usage` line (this raises an error if I include the nested group):

```
In [25]: parser.print_usage()
usage: ipykernel_launcher.py [-h] [-i INFILE] [-s SMILES [SMILES ...] | -n NAME
                             [NAME ...]] [-d DIRNAME] [-x EXTENSION]
```

The parser has a list of the groups:

```
In [26]: parser._mutually_exclusive_groups
Out[26]: 
[<argparse._MutuallyExclusiveGroup at 0x246dc1271c0>,
 <argparse._MutuallyExclusiveGroup at 0x246dc126560>]
```

And each group has a list of its `group_actions`:

```
In [27]: parser._mutually_exclusive_groups[0]._group_actions
Out[27]: [_StoreAction(option_strings=['-i', '--infile'], dest='infile', nargs=None, const=None, default=None, type=None, choices=None, required=False, help='Specify a file path to a names_smiles csv.', metavar=None)]

In [28]: parser._mutually_exclusive_groups[1]._group_actions
Out[28]: 
[_StoreAction(option_strings=['-s', '--smiles'], dest='smiles', nargs='+', const=None, default=None, type=None, choices=None, required=False, help='Specify your smiles (multiple possible).', metavar=None),
 _StoreAction(option_strings=['-n', '--name'], dest='name', nargs='+', const=None, default=None, type=None, choices=None, required=False, help='Specify (a) name(s) for your molecule.', metavar=None)]
```

`group1` has only one action, a rather meaningless specification.

If you don't like using "private" variables like this, you could collect your own list of Action references.  Each `add_argument` call returns an `Action` object.

If I parse an empty list (e.g. sys.argv without any commandline arguments:

```
In [30]: args = parser.parse_args([])    
In [31]: args
Out[31]: Namespace(infile=None, smiles=None, name=None, dirname=None, extension='xyz')
```

Except for `extension`, all defaults are `None`, so I can easily test for their use or not with:

```
In [33]: args.infile is None
Out[33]: True
```

Trying some other arguments

A valid case:

```
In [34]: args = parser.parse_args('-i foo.txt -s one two'.split())    
In [35]: args
Out[35]: Namespace(infile='foo.txt', smiles=['one', 'two'], name=None, dirname=None, extension='xyz')
```

and the error raised by the mutually exclusive test when trying to use both '-s' and '-n':

```
In [36]: args = parser.parse_args('-i foo.txt -s one two -n xxx'.split())
usage: ipykernel_launcher.py [-h] [-i INFILE] [-s SMILES [SMILES ...] | -n NAME
                             [NAME ...]] [-d DIRNAME] [-x EXTENSION]
ipykernel_launcher.py: error: argument -n/--name: not allowed with argument -s/--smiles
```

Any fancier 'group' testing - mutually exclusive, and, any etc, is best done in your own code after parsing.  I, and other devs, have decided it isn't worth the effort to add any facier grouping logic to the stock `argparse` code.  In my experience, formatting a meaningful `usage` line is particularly difficult.

Comment: So I missed it because I didn't look at the "_method" methods properly. It is possible but not sensible to do based on experience...Maybe I'll take my chances anyways.