# Add a second group of parameters that is totally mutually exclusive from the first group using argparse

Tags: python, argparse

I would like to know if its possible to use argparse to add a feature to a script I have written to make REST requests.  The current usage works great and looks like this:

```
$./prog.py -h
usage: prog.py [-h] [--headers [HEADER [HEADER ...]]]
                  [--queryparams [QUERY [QUERY ...]]] [--body [BODY]]
                  [METHOD] URL
```

I get that usage with something like this:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

position = self.parser.add_argument_group(
    title='Positional arguments',
    description='The only required argument is URL.'
)

position.add_argument(...)
position.add_argument(...)
```

What I want to do is add a second group of parameters that is totally mutually exclusive from the first group.

The usage for the second group will look something like this:

```
$./prog.py -h
usage: restcli.py [-h] request {refresh,update}
```

That is, if `request` is the first argument then the only valid option along with it is `refresh` or `update`.  If `request` isn't the first parameter assume that we are dealing with the orginal usage.

I think with subparsers I could almost do this but it would require a keyword to specify that I want the original non-request parser.  A usage in that case might look like this but I want to avoid that `original` keyword if possible:

```
$ ./prog.py -h
usage: prog.py [-h] {orignal,request}
```

Thanks in advance for any help you may be able to provide.

Comment: I'd recommend making a link/symlink to the program and checking `os.path.basename(sys.argv[0])` to decide how to behave, instead.  Invoked under the "old" name, do the old stuff; under the new name, have new, different argument parsng.

Comment: [Does argparse python support mutually exclusive groups of arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4770576) looks like it might be helpful.

Comment: I may just end up going with two separate commands as it seems clean and not as much of a hack.