# Allowing same option in different argparser group

Tags: python, argparse

Is it possible to allow the same argparse option to be in 2 different argparser groups?
This is actually what I want to achieve:-

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import argparse
... ... ...
g1 = parser.add_argument_group('g1')
g2 = parser.add_argument_group('g2')
g1.add_argument('--aa')
g1.add_argument('--common')
g2.add_argument('--bb')
g2.add_argument('--common')
```

... and the printed out help looks like this:-

```
usage: ...
... ... ...
g1:
    --aa [aa]
    --common [common]

g2:
    -bb [bb]
    --common [common]
```

But that is not possible, as argparse complains 'conflicting option string'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://bugs.python.org/issue10984 discusses adding an argument to two different `mutually_exclusive_groups`.  Doing the same with `argument_groups` is similar, though simpler.

```
import argparse
parser=argparse.ArgumentParser()
g1=parser.add_argument_group('group1')
g1.add_argument('-a')
caction=g1.add_argument('-c')
g2=parser.add_argument_group('group2')
g2.add_argument('-b')
g2._group_actions.append(caction)
parser.print_help()
```

It is a kludge, in the sense that it is modifying a 'private' attribute of the group.

The result:

```
usage: ipython [-h] [-a A] [-c C] [-b B]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit

group1:
  -a A
  -c C

group2:
  -b B
  -c C
```

Here's what's going on.  `add_argument` creates an `Action`, registers it with the `parser`, and returns it.  That's what `caction` captures.  If added to a group, it also registers the action with the group - by adding it to a `_group_actions` list.

If you do `g2.add_argument('-c')` you get an error because the parser already has an action with that option string.  The fact that you are 'adding' it to a different group is incidental.  The kludge gets around that by adding it to the group's list, without creating a new action.

In case it isn't obvious from the documentation, `argument_groups` are basically a 'help' convenience.  They do not affect parsing at all.  There are other ways you could customize the `help`.  For example, add `--common` to the `parser`, possibly with a `SUPPRESS` help line.  Then include a mention of it in the `description` for each group.

Comment: ah yes. That's actually what i was looking for. Thanks @hpaulj :)

Comment: btw, is there anywhere i can find the detail documentation of all the above mentioned stuff? I couldn't seem to find anywhere from the official argparse documentation on anything about the '_group_action' thingie.

Comment: You have to look in the `Lib/argparse.py` code file itself.  Documentation (should) covers the public API.  What I referenced is an implementation detail (note the `._`). There's a bit more chance that such details will change in later releases.   Also in an interactive shell (I use `Ipython`) you can look at the `parser` and `group` objects and their attributes.

Answer (score 1):

In this special case, you could make --aa and --bb mutually exclusive.

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
mutex = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
mutex.add_argument('--aa', action = 'store_true')
mutex.add_argument('--bb', action = 'store_true')
parser.add_argument('--common', action = 'store_true')
args = parser.parse_args()
```

which results in

```
usage: a.py [-h] [--aa | --bb] [--common]
```

Generally, argparse has the problem that you must create an option when calling add_argument.

Here's a somewhat related topic: [Does argparse (python) support mutually exclusive groups of arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770576/does-argparse-python-support-mutually-exclusive-groups-of-arguments)

There's a patch that allows you to have one argument in more than one mutually exclusive group:
http://bugs.python.org/issue10984

Another thing you can do is fiddle around with the argparse subparsers, or use another commandline parser altogether.

Comment: The OP is asking about argument groups, not mutually exclusive groups - which is the focus of `issue10984`.  I suspect the same kludge will work, though I'd have to test it.  Another thing to explore is a custom `conflict_handler`.

Comment: Thanks @timgeb. :) i was about to reply the same thing. But then, this is also something new to me. Let me try and see if this fits the bill. Thanks :)